# Ideas to perform a complicated encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I'm developping in C# an personnal/pratical application to encrypt some files, with no intention to share these encrypted files.
I read multiple articles about encryption, AES, the padding oracle attack, the HMAC and all this stuff. I surely didn't understand the half of all I have read but I think I've got the big picture. Or maybe not and the ideas I will talk about are completely ridiculous :)

So during the developpment I had ideas to "complexify" the encryption, so it would be more complicated to decrypt.

The first idea, that I've already developped, is to add randomly some extra bytes to the file before and after the encryption :
I read the file with a buffer, 1 megabyte at the time or wathever, and doing so I randomly add an array of random bytes in different locations in the file.
Something like that :

```
while ((read = streamIn.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    streamOut.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    if (random.Next(0, 2) == 1)
    {
        byte[] extraBytes = GenerateRandomBytes();
        streamOut.Write(extraBytes, 0, extraBytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Then I encrypt all these bytes with AES.
And then I just repeat the first step : I read the encrypted bytes with a buffer, and I randomly add some bytes.
I have already coded this, and of course if I don't take in consideration the extra bytes added after the encryption, I can't decrypt the file even with the good password/salt etc. And after the decryption if I don't take in consideration the extra bytes I added before the encryption, then I most likely get a corrupted file.
So I just wanted to know if it's a good idea, or if it's useless cause a good hacker would know which bytes are true and which bytes are false using some kind of mathematical function...

Another idea, that I didn't develop, is to split the content of the file, and encrypt each part seperately, and then concate them :
I read the full content of the file, I take the first half, I encrypt it with a password, a random IV etc, then I take the second half, I encrypt it with another password and another random IV, and then I concat the two encrypted parts and write all that in a file. I guess, in order to decrypt the file, I have to save the length of each encryption so I can split them and decrypt each part etc. That's not complicated of course. But again, I just want to know if it's completly useless or not.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think you are maybe overthinking this, and some of these ideas may actually make the encryption less secure. Also if you are doing this in .net then your security is probably lost anyway, there is nothing from stopping someone dissembling or peeking at your code in memory and reverse engineering it anyway

Comment: To add to what @TheGeneral is saying: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/lessons-learned-and-misconceptions-regarding-encryption-and-cryptology#2210 and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own are good reads.

Comment: I see where you are coming from but I'm afraid your additions are unnecessary - it's kinda like having a huge castle wall a kilometer high and then putting a bandaid on it "for extra security".  You're not wrong, but it's a pointless addition.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark and in fact can be making it worse. Its just like double encryption, it seems like it would be more secure, but in a lot of cases (and counter-intuitively) its actually not. adding anything known or can be figured out, will make an attack vector larger

Comment: ok ok. I really thought the first idea would be good, this is why I coded it already, but ok I drop it down, and I guess I just have to stick with "basics", random key, random IV and all that stuff. thx for the answers, and thx jnm2 for the links